# Make a Macro run automatically when there are any changes in the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a code to copy information from multiple sheets to multiple other sheets

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
 ByVal Source As Range)
Sub Unit_Separator()
Dim c As Range
Dim r As String 'Store the range here

Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Error Code 11")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Error Code 11")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Error Code 11")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Error Code 11")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1 'End of Error Code 11-Error11
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1 'End of Batches for Alisa-Reassign
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches Needing Unlocked")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches Needing Unlocked")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches Needing Unlocked")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches Needing Unlocked")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Angie")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Angie")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Angie")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batches for Angie")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Issues")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Issues")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Issues")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Issues")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in target sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Target.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I am sure my code could be better, but that isn't quite what I am looking for. All of this is modified from a macro I found and I wanted to know what code to add or modify to cause this to be ran anytime any changes are made anywhere on any sheet in the workbook.
I tried adding `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` to the beginning but that just errors out because there is already a range defined.

Comment: Check the [`Workbook_SheetChange` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange)

Comment: Changing `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)` to `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _ 
 ByVal Source As Range)` but all that does is throw back the message "expected end sub". One forum said to put the name of the macro in between that and `end sub` but that causes the code to not run.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your revised code.

Comment: Its been edited

Comment: Remove the `Sub Unit_Separator()` as a first step.

Comment: Removing that just recognizes `Dim Target As Worksheet` as a duplicate declaration.

Comment: That's why I said "first step" - there are other issues of course. Remove the `Dim Target As Worksheet` too :-)

Comment: That brings a second problem. I went ahead and removed that, but `Dim Target As Worksheet` was being used to define what sheet to copy information to.

Comment: I messed around with it a bit, redefined the original Target to Unit and It seemed to work until I got `Run-time error '28': Out of stack space`. I believe this is due to the code looping (because it is copying to the last four sheets in the spreadsheet while also checking every sheet for a change) but I am uncertain how to stop it from looping.

Comment: Most likely you need to turn off events: `Application.EnableEvents = False` and then turn them back on at the end: `Application.EnableEvents = True`. Make sure to include an error handler so that they are always reset to `True`.

Comment: That is what I thought, turns out I did that backwards last time I test it. Looks like it is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just about changing the name of the function, you need to do this inside the VBA project editor, as indicated by the following screenshot (mind the green rectangles):

[image: Screenshot]

Now I think I understand your problem, you have created following subroutine:

```
Sub Unit_Separator()
...
End Sub
```

And you want to launch this, based on a certain event. You have tried the following (by working inside the VBA project editor):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
 ByVal Source As Range)
Sub Unit_Separator()
...
End Sub
```

But this seems not to compile, and now you have people telling you to use this instead:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
 ByVal Source As Range)
Sub Unit_Separator()
...
End Sub
```

Which also doesn't work.

What you should do, is the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
 ByVal Source As Range)
...
End Sub
```

So, just remove the line with the ancient name for the subroutine. If you don't, you have the declaration of a subroutine within a subroutine, which can be interesting but not in your case: you would be declaring the subroutine without actually calling it.
So, as mentioned, just remove the `Sub Unit_Separator()` line and it should work.

Comment: I had it under Module previously, but I moved it to match what you showed and still get "expected end sub"

Comment: Well, you do have a "Private Sub ..." and inside that a "Sub Unit_Separator()", but you only have one "end sub", did you already try removing that "Sub Unit_Separator()" line?

Comment: That is the start of the Macro; would it work without it?

Comment: Removing that just recognizes `Dim Target As Worksheet` as a duplicate declaration.

Comment: @Hebert: I've adapted my answer according to your remark.

Comment: That still causes `Dim Target As Worksheet` to conflict.

Comment: You need to drop that line too: `Target` is already declared in the header of your subroutine, so you don't need to declare it a second time.

Comment: That brings a second problem. I went ahead and removed that, but `Dim Target As Worksheet` was being used to define what sheet to copy information to.

Comment: No. `Target` is the sheet which is being changed and which causes this subroutine to be launched. You can't change that. If you want to use a worksheet for another reason (like choosing a worksheet to copy something to, you can't use `Target` for that, you need to declare another one.

Comment: I messed around with it a bit, redefined the original Target to `Unit` and It seemed to work until I got `Run-time error '28': Out of stack space`

Comment: So now you are able to compile and run your code, but you have another problem. You seem to be progressing. As far as your new problem is concerned, I'd advise you to check this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/out-of-stack-space-error-28

Comment: I seem to recall a previous thread I looked at saying something about using `Application.EnableEvents = True` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` to avoid looping code. Considering this would be checking every sheet, could that be my problem? If so, and that isn't the solution, it could be fixed by having the `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` code not target the last four sheets in the book, but I don't know how to do that or if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution, as provided through comments, was to remove `Sub Unit_Separator()` and `Dim Target As Worksheet` and substitute `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _   ByVal Source As Range)`. Redefining the original `Target` variable I had did allow the code to run, but caused a `Run-time error '28': Out of stack space` error; this was solved by adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` to the beginning and `Application.EnableEvents = True` to the end. The final code, at least for now, is

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim c As Range
Dim r As String 'Store the range here

Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Unit As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Error Code 11")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Error Code 11")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Error Code 11")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Error Code 11")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1 'End of Error Code 11-Error11
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1 'End of Batches for Alisa-Reassign
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches Needing Unlocked")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches Needing Unlocked")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches Needing Unlocked")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches Needing Unlocked")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Alisa")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 5
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Angie")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Angie")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Angie")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Batches for Angie")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Other Issues")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 54")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "54" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Other Issues")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 53")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "53" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Other Issues")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 52")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "52" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = Me.Worksheets("Other Issues")
Set Unit = Me.Worksheets("Unit 51")

j = 33     ' Start copying to row 3 in Unit sheet
f = 9
For Each c In Source.Range("F2:F1500")   ' Do 1500 rows
    If c = "51" Then
        r = "A" & c.Row & ":" & "E" & c.Row 'Creating the range
       Source.Range(r).Copy Unit.Rows(j).Columns(f)
       j = j + 1
       End If
Next c
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Changed `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` to `Me.Worksheets` at the request of BigBen

Comment: If `ActiveWorkbook` refers to the one containing this code, then you can change all instances of it to `Me`.

Comment: plus one for adding the final solution, this is very useful for reference purposes.